# ActionBarActivity not shown Application icon

Tags: android

I have a problem. ActionBarActivity not shown Application icon.

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="belsci.play">

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:logo="@drawable/ic">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:icon="@drawable/ic" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AuthActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>


main_layout.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff181818"
        android:weightSum="1">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


MainActivity.java

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        }
    }
```

UPD0: I attached files main_layout.xml and MainActivity.java

Comment: How is your `ActionBar` configured? ABS, AppCompat, Toolbar?.. Any styles?

Comment: Please post your xml layout and your java class files.

Comment: I put the necessary files

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the appcompat-v7 version of the ActionBar, I could only get it to appear by adding the following to my ActionBarActivity class:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.tasking_icon_64);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

which is, I believe, roughly equivalent to CommonsWare's answer

Comment: It works, the icon appears, but there is an ugly space to the left of the icon, roughly the same size as the icon itself. Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

According to Material Design, action bars no longer show the application icon. You can enable this by calling `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` on the `ActionBar` that you get, for `appcompat-v7`, by calling `getSupportActionBar()` on your `ActionBarActivity`.